# Azure On-Premise Pipeline CMD error: migrate.exe returns error "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'"

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, windows-authentication, azure-devops-pipelines

The problematic script is:

```
1migrate.exe Core.dll /verbose /connectionString="DataSource=server-name;Initial Catalog=db-name;Integrated Security=True; "/connectionProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient "
```

I opened the machine that runs the Pipeline Agent and it performs the migration correctly.

When the same script runs under a [Command Line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) I get the error below:

> 2020-11-03T14:45:20.1962744Z ##[section]Starting: Command Line Script
> 2020-11-03T14:45:20.2058194Z
> ============================================================================== 2020-11-03T14:45:20.2058419Z Task         : Command line
> 2020-11-03T14:45:20.2058637Z Description  : Run a command line script
> using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
> 2020-11-03T14:45:20.2058833Z Version      : 2.177.2
> 2020-11-03T14:45:20.2058981Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
> 2020-11-03T14:45:20.2059204Z Help         :
> https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
> 2020-11-03T14:45:20.2059450Z
> ============================================================================== 2020-11-03T14:45:21.0758733Z Generating script.
> 2020-11-03T14:45:21.0836319Z Script contents:
> 2020-11-03T14:45:21.0849117Z migrate.exe Core.dll /verbose
> /connectionString="Data Source=server-name;Initial
> Catalog=db-name;Integrated Security=True; "
> /connectionProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient "
> 2020-11-03T14:45:21.1141401Z ========================== Starting
> Command Output ===========================
> 2020-11-03T14:45:21.1356562Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"
> /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL
> "C:\pipeline-agent_work_temp\6db07e4c-052c-4aa1-b103-db71bebfec26.cmd""
> 2020-11-03T14:45:24.3631400Z VERBOSE: Target database is:
> 'db-name' (DataSource: server-name, Provider:
> System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Explicit). 2020-11-03T14:45:24.4108063Z
> System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingException: Login failed
> for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. 2020-11-03T14:45:24.4111868Z
> at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
> runner) 2020-11-03T14:45:24.4118794Z    at
> System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Console.Program.Run()
> 2020-11-03T14:45:24.4122094Z    at
> System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Console.Program.Main(String[] args)
> 2020-11-03T14:45:24.4126803Z ERROR: Login failed for user 'NT
> AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. 2020-11-03T14:45:24.4862640Z
> ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'. 2020-11-03T14:45:24.5283178Z ##[section]Finishing: Command Line Script

This problem stops when I use SQL Server Authentication, unfortunately I need to use Windows Authentication.

Comment: Are there any Linked Server connections involved?  If so it could be a Kerberos Double-Hop scenario.

Comment: The On-Premise Agent deploys a sql schema on an DB located on another server.
Does this applies to the case you stated above?